# hql days between two dates

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to get the "Extracto" objects from the database where the difference in days between the current date and the final date of the Extracto object is less or equal 15, I didn't find useful information about this issue, is there a method in HQL or a manual calculation way to achieve this in the same query, without tampering the result set after the query is done??

here is my query:

```
String queryStr = "Select distinct E from Extracto E"
            + " left join fetch E.afiliados afiliado"
            + " left join fetch afiliado.personas personaAfiliado"
            + " left join fetch E.vehiculos vehiculo"
            + " left join fetch E.conductoresByIdConductor conductor1"
            + " left join fetch conductor1.personas persona1"
            + " left join fetch E.conductoresByIdConductor2 conductor2"
            + " left join fetch conductor2.personas persona2"
            + " left join fetch E.conductoresByIdConductor3 conductor3"
            + " left join fetch conductor3.personas persona3"
            + " left join fetch E.contrato contrato"
            + " left join fetch contrato.clientes cliente"
            + " left join fetch cliente.personas personaCliente"
            + " where E.servicio is null and"
            + " (E.fechaFinal - :fechaActual)<=15"
            + " and E.fechaFinal>:fechaActual)";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
where E.servicio is null and
      E.fechaFinal <= :fechaMax
      and E.fechaFinal>:fechaActual
```

Then provide `fetchaMax` parameter value as `fechaActual + 15 days`.